# Why I implement a Factory in this code with Dagger2 not working?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I excuse a simple code about dagger in kotlin but it not working in runtime. What is wrong and how to update this code?

I have a Notification class and I want to execute 'runNotification'.

```
    interface Notifications {

        fun runNotification()
    }

    class NotificationsImpl @Inject constructor(
        private val context: Application
    ) : Notifications {

        override fun runNotification() {
            Log.e("Notifications", "runNotification")
        }
    }
```

NotificationModule.kt

```
        @Module
    class NotificationModule {
            @Provides
            @Singleton
            fun providerNotifications(notificationsImpl: NotificationsImpl): Notifications = notificationsImpl
        }
```

ApplicationComponent.kt

```
    @Singleton
    @Component(modules = [NotificationModule::class])
    interface ApplicationComponent {

        @Component.Builder
        interface Builder {
            @BindsInstance
            fun application(application: Application): Builder

            @BindsInstance
            fun notificationModule(notificationModule: NotificationModule): Builder

            fun build(): ApplicationComponent
        }

        fun inject(application: Application)
    }
```

Code in Application

```
    DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .application(this)
                .notificationModule(NotificationModule())
                .build()
                .inject(this)
```

Code Test(this code 'notifications' return is NULL):

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var notifications: Notifications

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        notifications.updateNotification()
    }
}
```

Gradle:

```
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.17"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.17"

    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.17"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.17"

    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.17"
```

Comment: Are you using `DaggerActivity`?

Comment: No, I used AppCompatActivity

Comment: Then you need to create component for your activity and bind your activity to it. Otherwise Dagger won't know your activity needs something

Comment: It's working. Thanks